# Visual Studio: Alternatives to "find all references"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

I wonder if there is either a VS (Ultimate) solution or an Extension which can help me with the following. I use VisualStudio Community and C#.

I use "find all references" a lot but I also have the issue that my code has many objects which extend an Interface or base class and "find all references" shows all of these overridden methods, but not the one that I want to find.

Another thing that I wondered is if I can search for explicit operations such as assignments only. Some variables are used 1000 times but are assigned just once. It would be great if this can be found quicker. So is any of this possible?

Comment: I don't think there's a "built in" way, but a trick to search for only the override usages is to temporarily remove the `override` keyword, then "find all references" will work like you want. As for, "Some variables are used 1000 times but are assigned just once.", another "trick" is to simply use the search feature and hope no one used a obfuscation or odd white spaces, e.g., just search for "variable =" to find all assignments, but then you lose stuff like `variable +=` I guess..

Comment: Best tool for this kind of work is ReSharper, although it´s not for free it ads huge features to find members, overrides, member-setters and getters, and also to enhance your code-quality by defining code-contracts.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. These workarounds could help and I might take a look at the ReSharper Trial, it sounds interesting.